# Literal meaning of 打ってあります in this sentence

Tags: meaning

> **盲人のための点字が打ってあります** 
>
>   moujin no tame no tenji ga utte arimasu
>   *Braille has been provided for the blind (book's translation)*

The book I'm reading translates it as [to provide].
But in any dictionary I check, it means to hit/strike. I know that this book I'm reading likes to change the translation a bit off from the literal meaning.

So I'm wondering what is the literal meaning of this sentence?
Is this incorrect? >> "Braille is prepared to tackle the need of the blind."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the 打つ is used in the sense of:

> うつ【打つ・撃つ・討つ】
>   ❷㋒ 記号や番号などを書きつける。**[付]{ふ}す。つける。**「文末に句点を打つ」

in 明鏡国語辞典.

This 打つ is often used like this:

- 名前にはふりがなを**打って**ください。
  (commonly seen in a registration/application form)
  ≂ ふりがなを[振]{ふ}ってください・ふりがなをつけてください。
  "Please add Furigana/Ruby to your name."
  ... even when you're writing it by hand.
- この絵本は、漢字に全部[読]{よ}み[仮名]{がな}が**うって**あります。
  "Pronunciation/ruby has been added to all kanji in this picture book."

So I think the 打つ in your example 盲人のための点字が打ってあります is also used in the meaning of 「つける」 or 「[付]{ふ}す」, literally "put", "attach", or "add".

Comment: In this sense, it's similar to the english verb "enter" in the use "enter a form" / "fill out"

Answer (score 8):

打つ here means "to punch" (to punch Braille dots)

Answer (score 2):

打つ is also used in expression like キーボードを打つ,  "to type on a keyboard".

Examples  from  the dictionary:

> 6 〔キーをたたく〕
> この書類をワープロで打ってくれ
> Please type this document on a word processor.
>
> 彼に祝電を打った
> I sent him a congratulatory telegram.
> http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/5627/meaning/m0u/%E6%89%93%E3%81%A4/

From that the meaning probably expanded to "print letters".

So the translation becomes:

> 点字が打ってあります 
> The braille letters have already been printed.